# AngularJs onClick Prevent scrolling to the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am creating a web site, i am using Angular JS and bootstrap to build the page. 
I have a one problem dough on my home page i have a hamburger menu button, lets say i scroll half way through my web page click the hamburger, I am then automaticly moved to the top of the page.

I really do not want this to happen i want the user to stay on the same location on the page after they click the hamburger menu. Dont want to move them back to the top:

HTML:

ANgularJS:

```
        scope.menuClick = function() {
            $rootScope.MobileVisible = !$rootScope.MobileVisible;
            scope.visibleSearchBar = false;
        };
```

From the given code snaps is it possible to direct me to a desired solution..?

Comment: could you please provide the HTML markup containing ng-click="menuClick"?

Answer (score 3):

You should use preventDefault() method.
Try this:

```
  scope.menuClick = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $rootScope.MobileVisible = !$rootScope.MobileVisible;
        scope.visibleSearchBar = false;
    };
```

Comment: Hey thx for suggested but i have tired it and it does not do the trick :/

Comment: Can you create a plunker to demonstrate a problem ?

Comment: @Tomazi: You have to pass the event to your function now, maybe you've missed that: `<a href="#" ng-click="menuClick($event)">Foobar</a>`

Answer (score 0):

please check this code

```
angular.module('moduleName',[]).config( ['$anchorScrollProvider', 
    function($anchorScrollProvider) {
        $anchorScrollProvider.disableAutoScrolling();
    }]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably won't be relevant to everyone, but for me the problem was that the parent element of the accordions had a height that was being dynamically set every frame. For some reason, this caused the page to scroll to the top whenever an accordion was toggled. I was using Angular:

```
<div class="scrollable" [ngStyle]="{ 'max-height': 'calc(' + getHeight() + 'px - 6rem)' }">
    <!-- List of accordions go in here -->
</div>
```

Removing the ngStyle fixed the issue. You could also replace getHeight function with a variable height which is calculated once in ngAfterViewInit.

```
<div class="scrollable" [ngStyle]="{ 'max-height': 'calc(' + height + 'px - 6rem)' }">
    <!-- List of accordions go in here -->
</div>
```